# Spring mvc rest Controller unit testing with testNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, testng

I have a rest controller in Spring mvc application like below:
I searched lot of examples on net, but most of them are with junit.I want to do unit test with testNg

public class SomeController {

```
@Autowired
private GeneralManager generalManager;

@Autowired
private DataManager dataManager;



@RequestMapping(value="/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
public Object processSubmit(@RequestBody String inputData, @RequestHeader("authtoken") String atoken) {

    MessageEntity msgObj = ""
    if(generalManager.checktoken(atoken)){
        try{
            return dataManager.processSubmit(inputData);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred in submitting the  data",e);
            msgObj.setMessageId(1);
            msgObj.setMessage("Exception in processSubmit. Failed to submit the  data.");

        }
    }else{
        return new "Exception"
    }

    return msgObj;
}
```

I need to unit test the above code.The input is Json String(big Json payload).
How do I unit test the above controller with testNG in my Spring mvc application?

In actual method, I am taking inputdata string(that Json payload) and building entities by extracting json payload.How do I pass this json String(payload) to testNG unit test class?